# After form submit how to prevent page refresh and make it to remain in same tab section

Tags: php, forms

I am using a bootstrap template which has all page code in index page and redirecting the tab for all the pages by using id with in index page.In contact form tab section i have created a form to perform file upload and after i have submit my form it redirects to home page tab.how to make it to remain in same page.I have written the php action too in the same page but its not supporting.

Until i have refer we cant able to use ajax in fileupload hence we need to use this plugin.[jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) but i have no idea on how to implement this plugin in my form.

```
<form id="attach" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
  <p>
    <label for="tele">Upload Your Resume:</label><br>
    <input id="tele" name="filename" type="file" />
  </p> 
</div>
<input class="formbtn" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

   // Set the "To" email address
   $to="admin@abc.com";

    //Subject of the mail
   $subject="Join Us E-mail with Resume attachment";

   // Get the sender's name and email address plug them a variable to be used later
   $from = stripslashes($_POST['name'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email']).">";

    // Check for empty fields

    if($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']==""){
            echo '<font style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:11px; color:#F3363F; font-weight:bold">Please upload your resume</font>';
        }


    // Get all the values from input
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Check the email address
    if (!eregi( "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email_address))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
    }

   // Now Generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
   $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

   // Now Store the file information to a variables for easier access
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
   $type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
   $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
   $size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];

   // Now here we setting up the message of the mail
   $message = "\n\n Name: $name \n\n Email: $email_address \n\nMessage: \n\n $message \n\nHere is your file: $file_name";

   // Check if the upload succeded, the file will exist
   if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

      // Check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
      if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

         // Now Open the file for a binary read
         $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

         // Now read the file content into a variable
         $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

         // close the file
         fclose($file);

         // Now we need to encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
         $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
     }

      // Now we'll build the message headers
      $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

      // Next, we'll build the message body note that we insert two dashes in front of the  MIME boundary when we use it
      $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";

      // Now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as an attachment, then add the file content and set another boundary to indicate that the end of the file has been reached
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
         " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
         //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
         //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

      // Thats all.. Now we need to send this mail... :)
      if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
      {
         ?>
         <div><center><h1>Mail Sent successfully !!</h1></center></div>
         <?php
      }else
      {
         ?>
         <div><center>
           <h1>Error !! Unable to send Mail..</h1></center></div>
         <?php
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` to prevent form submitting

Comment: i have tried it out but its not supporting

Comment: Post what have you tried

Comment: <script>$('#attach').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // disable default submit behaviour of the browser
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize()); // handle the post via ajax
}); </script> i have tried like this but its not supporting

Answer (score 1):

Do not use any action path so it will call the same page (As per the above current scrip) :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I have removed it but still it is redirecting to home page tab